# Failed to load com32 file vesamenu.c32 on centOS installation

Tags: centos, boot, dual-boot

I've already seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612746/ubuntu-live-usb-wont-boot-failed-to-load-com32-file-menu-c32) , but it didn't work! I tested both CentOS 6 and 7 and I got the same error.

Interestingly enough when I try to install it on Vm, everything goes smoothly.

[image]

Comment: What is your operating system , what is the program used to create the bootable usb?

Comment: I used many program such as flash boot...universal boot installer...and my OS is windows 10 pro

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on trying a USB live CD of Porteus - v4.0rc4-x86_64 (but I have had this happen before).

Strangely, it seems almost impossible to get a real solution to this problem. One solution which might work for you (although it didn't for me) might be replacing the vesamenu.c32 file with the same from a more recent syslinux. This is one of the suggestions I came across but it can't be the solution to my problem as the syslinux in the iso file I have seems pretty recent.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is looking for an answer. I don't really have fix but a workaround. If you hit tab at the **boot:** prompt and then type **automatic-gui** and hit enter it will move on to the install process. I've done this several times and it works perfectly for me every time. Sorry for the blurry image but my cell phone couldn't focus properly.
[image: The image attached is what I see right after hitting tab]